# elastic beanstalk deploy same branch to multiple environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to deploy the same branch to the *production*  and *staging* environment.

This is my `config.yml` file.

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: production
global:
  application_name: ...
  default_ec2_keyname: ...
  default_platform: PHP 7.0
  default_region: eu-west-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```

how can i do?

I tried `eb use` but it works just one-to-one (branch-to-env). I need one-to-many (branch-to-envs).

Comment: Have you tried changing `environment: production` to `environment: staging`?

Comment: yep but i need both :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can target a particular environment at deployment time by passing an argument to `eb deploy` - i.e. `eb deploy production` or `eb deploy staging`.

However, that will perform the package and upload steps twice; while the contents of the two packages should be the same, they will not be binary identical. In my opinion, a better workflow is to use `eb deploy` to deploy to a non-prod environment, and then to use the EB web console to deploy that exact same application version to production.

Comment: While i was waiting for answers i did this in my gitlab pipeline deploy-flow. 
I'm probably going to mark this as valid answer since i am adopting this method right now.

It bother me that there's no good documentation about the `branch-defaults:`

Comment: Won't be the last time you're bothered by Amazon's documentation... :)

Comment: I'd like to live in my fantasy world where attempting to follow Amazon's documentation doesn't error out at every step until you Google the problem 17 different ways